practice Git on EF Migrations
We have multiple branches in git, contains multiple development circles on the same project.
each one related to different client with some different features. all projects have common DB. and common migration. problem is when we want to apply the entityframework migration on all projects, merges can bring other changes other than migrations. which can mix branches and causes critical issues.
how can we practice the git with those migrations without making mix between branches and make all branches up to date with the migrations updates?
for example I have those main branches :
main
develop
X-Develop
Y-Develop
we want keep main away for now, main can collect all branches together after development is over [Future work]. but during development and current deployments, we cannot make X-Develop and Y-Develop and develop mixed.
X-Develop and Y-Develop can take changes and merges from develop all changes everything, but we cannot bring X-Develop to Y or to develop, we cannot bring Y to X-Develop or to develop.
I already tried solution like making migrations on develop and keeping X and Y synced with develop. But sometimes if we wasn't careful all of us all employees there will be a lot of hours to be spent on fixing the issue and doing rebase as you know is a nightmare when there're too many commits.

Maybe my anwer will help you (partially) Strategy for handling multiple EF Migrations
